# camel split big sql result in smaller chunks

Tags: sql, apache-camel

Because of memory limitation i need to split a result from sql-component (`List<Map<column,value>>`) into smaller chunks (some thousand).

I know about

```
from(sql:...).split(body()).streaming().to(...)
```

and i also know

```
.split().tokenize("\n", 1000).streaming()
```

but the latter is not working with `List<Map<>>` and is also returning a String. 
Is there a out of the Box way to create those chunks? Or do i need to add a custom aggregator just behind the split? Or is there another way?

**Edit**
Additional info as requested by soilworker:
At the moment the sql endpoint is configured this way:

```
SqlEndpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("sql:select * from " + lookupTableName + "?dataSource=" + LOOK_UP_DS,
                                           SqlEndpoint.class);
// returns complete result in one list instead of one exchange per line.
endpoint.getConsumerProperties().put("useIterator", false);
// poll interval
endpoint.getConsumerProperties().put("delay", LOOKUP_POLL_INTERVAL);
```

The route using this should poll once a day (we will add CronScheduledRoutePolicy soon) and fetch a complete table (view). All the data is converted to csv with a custom processor and sent via a custom component to proprietary software. The table has 5 columns (small strings) and around 20M entries.
I don't know if there is a memory issue. But i know on my local machine 3GB isn't enough. Is there a way to approximate the memory footprint to know if a certain amount of Ram would be enough?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you get a List<Map<column,value>> as result of your sql-consumer the whole data is already in memory, so the splitter called after the sql-consumer has no effect on lowering the memory consumption. Could you please provide some more information about the parameters of your sql-consumer? Maybe consumer.useIterator=true or maxMessagesPerPoll is a viable solution for you.

Comment: Can you set useIterator=true and append each line you get from the consumer to your csv file?

Comment: is there a way to know if i received the last line of a poll (i need this info for start up logic)? With this i could just aggregate some line and then send them to target.

Comment: I'm not rly sure if the CamelSqlRowCount header value is what you need. Another thing that could work if you need a counter is the batch=true parameter, then you get a batchsize property(Exchange.Batch_size)

Comment: Have you tried setting the JVM memory settings for the route? Sounds like you are experiencing a out of memory error and this should would indicate that perhaps your jvm settings are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

maxMessagesPerPoll will help you get the result in batches